# Abstract external library in Angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs, global, angularjs-service, abstraction

Some external libraries that I use together with Angular create global variable, which I don't really like because it pollutes global scope. For example PaperJS, when include it in the page, it will create a global variable "paper" in global scope

Anybody has any idea how to create Angular services to wrap those external libraries so that it's no longer exposed in global scope?

Comment: Sure, create a service that stores a reference to the globally stored object and then removes the globally stored object. it will still however be globally available between the time when the library is included and the service is initialized.

Comment: thanks, i'm also thinking about this, and just looking for any best practice if available. Is service or constant/value more appropriate for this case?